# Why does XCode suggest (and compile) non-existant object properties?

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa

I'm an experienced programmer, but new to Mac development (in XCode and Swift).  10 minutes into my first 'hello world' program, I've found <strike>what I think is a horrendous bug in XCode / Swift.  But maybe a misunderstanding on my part.</strike> some behaviour which new users wouldn't expect and which makes it very easy to accidentally write unsafe code.

Essentially XCode thinks that a property exists when actually it doesn't.

The tiny application below demonstrates this (there is also a simple GUI with a text box and a button linked to inputBox and clickedButton).  It reports no errors, and XCode will happily compile and run it.  But when the clickedButton action is called, it crashes saying: "[NSTextField placeholderString]: unrecognized selector"

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputBox: NSTextField!

    @IBAction func clickedButton(sender:AnyObject) {

        let placeholder : String = inputBox.placeholderString!
        let name : String = (inputBox.stringValue == "") ? placeholder : inputBox.stringValue
        println("Hi: \(name)!")

    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    }

}
```

I have since found out that NSTextField does not have the property placeholderString, in fact placeholderString is a property of the related NSTextFieldCell object, which you get to using the cell() method.  The line below does work as expected:

```
let placeholder : String = (inputBox.cell()!).placeholderString!!
```

So, the question is:

1) Why does XCode's auto completion feature suggest 'placeholderString' to me as a possible option after typing 'inputBox.', when inputBox is a NSTextField object and that has no placeholderString property.

2) Why does this code compile?  Surely the compiler would know what properties can be accessed and throw an error?

Is this just a bug in XCode (I am using version 6.2 (6C131e) on Mavericks)?  Or is there something deeper I haven't understood about the interaction between Swift and Objective-C and the Cocoa framework?

**Update**
Thomas Kilian gave me a useful tip - ctrl click to see the definition.  So I ctrl-clicked the placeholder property and saw this:

```
@availability(OSX, introduced=10.10)
var placeholderString: String?
```

My system is 10.9.  So I guess that explains why I can't access that property.  But, my app's Deployment Target is set to OS X 10.9.  So XCode should know that the property is not available, and it shouldn't compile.  Right?  Is XCode failing to understand the @availability attribute?

**Further Update**

gnasher729 explained the situation pretty clearly in the accepted answer below.

So, while this is expected documented behaviour and not a 'bug', it still means it's extremely easy to write code which will compile just fine, and then crash with a runtime error on the target device.  XCode actively suggests methods which don't work.  The only way to be sure your code won't crash seems to be to look up every single method you use in the docs and check it yourself.  gnasher729 suggested just using an older SDK, but Apple doesn't provide any way to downgrade.  I personally think it's unacceptable, especially considering safety is one of the main selling points of Swift.

The good news is that the XCode guys obviously thought so too, because Swift 2 (in XCode 7) introduces automatic availability checking, which checks that every method you use will work on the target platform.  It also lets you put code inside an `if #available` block to run code conditionally on the platform and version.

So my example above can be safely written as:

```
var placeholder : String
if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
    // use latest methods
    placeholder = inputBox.placeholderString!
} else {
    // otherwise fall back to old way
    placeholder = (inputBox.cell as! NSTextFieldCell).placeholderString!
}
```

And XCode will check it all automatically, which is great.

At the time of writing Swift2 / XCode7 is still in beta.  More info on their blog:  https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=29

Comment: `placeholderString` is available from 10.10 on (cmd-click on the identifier to see the definition). I guess you did run under pre-10.10?

Comment: Hmm, ok, so I see this in the definition above placeholderString: @availability(OSX, introduced=10.10).  So I guess that explains why XCode might have suggested it.  But, shouldn't availability=10.10 prevent it from compiling on my 10.9 system?  Or at least warn me or something?  Instead of just crashing with a runtime error.  That's horrendous!

Comment: No. You can compile where you want. The AppStore prevents it from being sold in a pre-10.10 environment. You also can/must set the deployment target for your project correctly.

Comment: You assume that you found a serious bug within ten minutes of using Xcode, that nobody else has ever noticed? Isn't that a very careless assumption? Whenever something doesn't work, your assumption should be that you made a mistake. And then you need to find out which mistake you made.

Comment: gnasher729 - I didn't assume it was a serious bug that no-one else had noticed.  I said right at the start "maybe a misunderstanding on my part".  Seems like it was.  Thank you for your answer - it was very helpful.  Maybe I was hasty to use the word 'bug', but, Swift is pretty new, and in my first hour of using it, just trying stuff out in the playgrounds, I had to restart XCode 5 or 6 times because it crashed.  I was getting the feeling that perhaps Swift is still not very stable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On every iOS and MacOS X version, there are three important version numbers: The version number of the SDK that you are using (what you use in your compiler), the version number of the lowest iOS or MacOS X version that allows your app to run, and the version number of the actual device your code is running on.

The SDK number tells the compiler which OS methods you can call. If your SDK is MacOS X 10.9 then you cannot call methods from MacOS X 10.10, the compiler doesn't allow it.

If your deployment version (the lowest version that allows the app to run) is for example 10.9 and the SDK is 10.10 then methods that only exist will crash if you try to call them when running on 10.9. You need to check this manually; Swift 2 has methods that make this very easy.

In this situation, the app will not run on 10.8 at all. It will run on 10.9 but crash if you use 10.10 methods. It will run fine on 10.9.

The idea behind the setup is that it lets you use new features running on a new OS version, while being able to run on an old OS version, assuming you are careful to avoid new calls.

If that's too complicated for you, either use the 10.9 SDK (no 10.10 calls for you, ever), or deploy on 10.10 only (your app won't run on 10.9).